# One hour difference, but only for some dates

Tags: php, date, datediff, days

Why between those dates I get 5,9.... and if I use another year I get 6 ???? It only happens with March and 2008... why is there an hour difference ???

```
<?php
 $from = '2008-03-04';
 $to = '2008-03-10';

 echo datediff($from,$to);

 $from = '2010-03-04';
 $to = '2010-03-10';

 echo datediff($from,$to);

 function datediff($from,$to)
 {
  $diff = strtotime($to) - strtotime($from);
  $diff = $diff/(60*60*24);
  return $diff;
 }
?>
```

Comment: My guess would be PHP, considering that's the only common language I know with `strtotime` as a std. library function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Daylight Saving Time](http://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/us-daylight-saving-starts-march-9-2008.html).

Comment: Yes, Is PHP
but i don't know if is a PHP error or a TIMESTAMP one

Comment: Neither. It's just a fact that there were only 143 hours between midnight of March 4, 2008 and midnight of March 10, 2008, instead of 144.

Comment: why? a day has 24hs. Why there?

Comment: Nope. Days that are undergoing a DST change have either 23 or 25 hours.