# PHP datetime difference in seconds missing one hour

Tags: php, datediff

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [One hour difference, but only for some dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233666/one-hour-difference-but-only-for-some-dates)

Why:

```
strtotime('2012-11-01 00:00:00') - strtotime('2012-10-01 00:00:00')
```

is returning:

```
2674800
```

When the right value is:

```
2678400
```

is missing one hour.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because your locale (as defined by `date.timezone` in php.ini) probably experienced a time change sometime in October, due to daylight savings time.

Comment: +1 Why do people forget about DST so easily?

Comment: @deceze I admit to having forgotten it myself, so now that's the first thing I think of.  I saw at least a half dozen questions related to it about a month ago.

Comment: Damn! You right, i forgot. Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Good so you didn't have to look too far to get a dupe?

Comment: @PeeHaa I think this one is actually a clearer question than the one linked as a dupe, though I CV'd and community-wiki'd this.